# Получение данных из функции javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, геолокация

Доброго дня.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

```js
 weatherUrl = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   function(position) {
     var latitude = Math.round(position.coords.latitude);
     var longitude = Math.round(position.coords.longitude);
     var weatherUrlSrc = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&lang=ru&units=metric';
     return weatherUrlSrc;
   });
```

В результате в weatherUrl пусто.
Подозреваю, что ошибка банальна, но отыскать её не могу.

UPD: Отредактировал, как и советовали, но в другую функцию всё равно приходит пустая переменная:

```js
  //получаем местоположение и формируем URL для получения погоды для текущего местоположения
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) {
      var latitude = Math.round(position.coords.latitude);
      var longitude = Math.round(position.coords.longitude);
      var weatherUrlSrc = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&APPID=df159a0a244e169d3d6cb88301a23b9f&lang=ru&units=metric';
      weatherUrlGeo = weatherUrlSrc;
    });
  //получаем и обрабатываем текущую погоду
  recieveData.fetchData(weatherUrlGeo).success(function(data) {
    $scope.weather = recieveData.procData(data);
  });
```

В итоге разобрался с вашей помощью, спасибо всем! Вот итоговый рабочий кусок кода:

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(position) {
    var weatherUrlSrc = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='
    weatherUrlSrc += Math.round(position.coords.latitude);
    weatherUrlSrc += '&lon=';
    weatherUrlSrc += Math.round(position.coords.longitude);
    weatherUrlSrc += '&APPID=df159a0a244e169d3d6cb88301a23b9f&lang=ru&units=metric';
    recieveData.fetchData(weatherUrlSrc).success(function(data) {
      $scope.weather = recieveData.procData(data);
    });
  });
```

Comment: у тебя getCurrentPosition КАЛбек , то есть вместо 'weatherUrlGeo = weatherUrlSrc;' нужно вызвать ф-цию и передать ей weatherUrl параметром

Answer (score 1):

на вскидку это должно выглядеть приблизительно так

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) {
        var weatherUrlSrc = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='
        weatherUrlSrc += Math.round(position.coords.latitude);
        weatherUrlSrc += '&lon=';
        weatherUrlSrc += Math.round(position.coords.longitude);
        weatherUrlSrc += '&APPID=df159a0a244e169d3d6cb88301a23b9f&lang=ru&units=metric';
        function(weatherUrlSrc) {
            recieveData.fetchData(weatherUrlGeo).success(function(data) {
                $scope.weather = recieveData.procData(data);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Почти в точку, только вторая функция лишняя!  Спасибо!

Comment: ну писал по быстрому навскидку, поэтому и написал "приблизительно", я не гуру JS поэтому мог и накосячить

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаете функцию в качестве параметра, она не может ничего возвращать. Если вы хотите где то поменять URL, то вы должны сделать это в этой функции

```
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
       function(position) {
         var latitude = Math.round(position.coords.latitude);
         var longitude = Math.round(position.coords.longitude);
         var weatherUrlSrc = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&lang=ru&units=metric';
         *вместо return вставляем полученные URL куда надо*
          weatherUrl = weatherUrlSrc 
       });
```

Comment: Строго говоря, любая функция что-то возвращает. И запретить написать `return` нельзя и в описанном случае. А вот то, что результат `return` не попадёт в `weatherUrl` - это да.

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены что в функцию `getCurrentPosition` в качестве параметра надо url отдавать? Судя по коду, вы вызываете функцию и передаете ей, по сути, `url` (`weatherUrlSrc`), и ждете, что `weatherUrl` примет значение еще какого-то `url` (исходя из названия переменной).

Comment: да тут классический КАЛбэк , 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition' асинхронная и когда мы вызываем 'recieveData.fetchData' в weatherUrlGeo ещё ничего нету